# Getting Errors memory from Pandas dataframe from CSV

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have never received this error before in Python and I was wondering why it occurs and what to do about it. This file is 11.7mb

```
relationships = pd.read_csv('relationships.tsv')
```

> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py",
>   line 1995, in read
>       data = self._reader.read(nrows)   File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 899, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read   File
>   "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 914, in
>   pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory   File
>   "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 968, in
>   pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows   File
>   "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 955, in
>   pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows   File
>   "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 2172, in
>   pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error pandas.errors.ParserError:
>   **Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 6, saw 2**

Comment: have a look into your file. At line 6 there is a seperator which leds pandas interpret it as 2 columns while the first 5 lines only have 1 column

Comment: If this is a `tsv` file, you likely want to explcitly state that your separator is the `tab`, i.e. `df = pd.read_csv('relationships.tsv', sep='\t')`

Comment: Where is there a memory error here ???

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation for read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) says

> sep : str, default ‘,’

If you have a tab-separate file, you need to explicitly pass

```
df = pd.read_csv('relationships.tsv', sep='\t')
```